# How to POST selected option to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, selectlistitem

I have created the following dropdown list and also the conditional check that will output the "block" -> details that are associated with the options. See below for e.g:

```js
function val(ddbox) {

         //NEW
        if ( ddbox.options[ddbox.selectedIndex].value == "Others"){
                document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = "block";
        }else{
                document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = "none";
        }
         if( ddbox.options[ddbox.selectedIndex].value != "Others"){
                document.getElementById("NumberChosen").style.display = "block";
        }else{
                document.getElementById("NumberChosen").style.display = "none";
        }
}
```

```html
 <li class="bigfield">
                        <select name ="ddbox" id="ddbox" onchange = "val(this)">
                        <option value ="0"> Select Number..</option>
                        <option value ="Option 1"> 1</option>
                        <option value ="Option 2"> 2</option>
                        <option value ="Option 3"> 3</option>
                        <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
                        </select>
                </li>


                <!--when user select "Others"-->
                <div id = "extradiv" style ="display:none">
                <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Enter your Num" type="text" name="OthersNum" id="OthersNum"/></li>
                <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Number Characteristics" type="text" name="NumberOthersCharacteristics" id="NumberOthersCharacteristics"/></li>
                <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="why do you like this number" type="text" name="NumberOthersLikefactor" id="NumberOthersLikefactor"/></li>
                 </div>

                 <!--when user select other options-->
                <div  id = "NumberChosen" style ="display:none" >
               <li class="bigfield"><input value="NumChosen" type="text" name="NumChosen" id="NumChosen" readonly></li>
                <li class="bigfield"><input value="Num Chosen Characteristic" type="text" name="NumChosenCharactersitics" id="NumChosenCharactersitics" readonly/></li>
                <li class="bigfield"><input value="Num Chosen Likes" type="text" name="NumChoseLikes" id="NumChoseLikes" readonly/></li>
                 </div>
```

I have made each chosen option to reference to the details in  and when user clicks "Others", it will reference to the input field in . Hence the  field form is done within the View of the MVC framework.

To ensure that on submission and the values are POST correctly to the controller code, I have made the following error log within the controller code to check on the values captured from the form. The following error_logs as shown:

```
       error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_ipad,Num: ".$_POST['OthersNum']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/*.log");
       error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad, NumChar: ".$_POST['NumberOthersCharacteristics']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/*.log");
       error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad, NumLikes: ".$_POST['NumberOthersLikefactor']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/*.log");

       error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad,NumberChosen: ".$_POST['NumChosen']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/*.log");
       error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad, NumChosenChar: ".$_POST['NumChosenCharacteristics']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/*.log");           error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad, NumChosenLikes: ".$_POST['NumChoseLikes']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/*.log");
```

**Now, this is the main issue that I am facing, both the error logs will always show when I run the following terminal command: 'tail -f *.log', for example, if I were to select "Others" in the option list and key in the respective fields, and submit the form, values will POST to the controller code and the error log will not only show the values for "OthersNum", it will also show the details of the NumChosen. That is not the result I want, I am looking at the error log only posting details that have been entered for "Others" option and not display the details associated for the other options as well**

Hence, the redundant error_log is shown, from what I understand, all values from the form are POST -ed to the controller. Hence, how am I able to edit the existing code such that only the chosen selected option will be POST-ed over to the controller?

Comment: What is the issue ? Are you unable to read the form fields in POST request ?

Comment: @RayonDabre The issue: When I post the values from the form fields to the controller code, the error_log post all the details out, not what I want. I only want the error log to post the details that are associated with the chosen select list. At this point in time, It is posting everything, how am I able to only show the details on what has been selected in the select list

Comment: If you dont want those form fields to be posted, you need to remove them from DOM or set their attribute as `disabled`. Morover, you can simply put a condition in your php code with respctive option selected..

Comment: @RayonDabre, If I were to set those fields as disabled, it will not show even if the options for those details are selected. I need the details to show only when the option is selected. Condition in php code? e,g?

Comment: you can play with the attribute as per the selection of option, as you are doing to display the details. AT php side you can just check `if($_POST['whatever_you_want'])`

Comment: @RayonDabre but that would mean that at the controller side, it will display  the details right?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is from the if statement, you don't want to use multiple if statement for same conditions, yours if statement should be,

```
function val(ddbox) {
        if ( ddbox.options[ddbox.selectedIndex].value == "Others"){
                document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById("NumberChosen").style.display = "none";
        }else{
                document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("NumberChosen").style.display = "block";
        }
}
```

Use single if statement for similar conditions, Hope this works...